# Finding BLDC motor amperage and needed battery power

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, motor, brushless-dc-motor

Im currently trying to build a motorized sofa chair. Physical things such as structure is of no issue to me, however the issue comes with finding motors and batteries that will work together and not fry it instantly and whatnot while also being strong enough. Assuming the person is 150lbs on average and the chair is maybe 70lbs, however im not confirmed on the latter weight (I will be stripping out the heavy insides like motors & metal). I have this 36V/48V 1000W motor off of amazon on my wishlist ([https://www.amazon.com/L-faster-UNITEMOTOR-Controller-Throttle-Motorcycle/dp/B07DQMC8Q6?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DQMC8Q6)) alongside batteries from batteryhookup being either 10 of these SPIM08HP 3.7V 16AH batteries wired in series (https://batteryhookup.com/products/2x-spim08hp-3-7v-8ah-cells-with-threaded-insert) or three of these 6.4Ah 48V batteries in parallel (https://batteryhookup.com/products/samsung-12s-43-2v-8-5ah-367-2wh-lithium-ion). Im not sure as to whether this motor will be powerful enough to gain substantial speed, preferably 15mph at max or high but mostly aiming to make sure it can consistently move without struggling or completely die on me and fry it.

Also, whatever battery I do get, would something like this charge it? [https://www.amazon.com/Charger-Battery-Balance-Discharger-Adapter/dp/B07R18YNZQ/ref=sr_1_15?keywords=drone+battery+charger&qid=1687542120&sr=8-15](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07R18YNZQ) I already own one better than this used for fpv drone batteries I just cannot find the exact specs online and do not have it with me right now

Should I be getting a different motor, different battery, etc? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: This question is very broad and contains many separate details. And direct product recommendations are off topic here. I made a similar fun thing. I mounted two e-scooters parallel below the chair and coupled the steering.